# Reading data from a GPS device on a GlassFish Server

Tags: java, gps, glassfish

I'm developing a system to get the location of buses every 5 minutes through a **GPS device** i have installed on the bus. I have written simple socket server to get the data but i'm at loss on figuring a out how to integrate that to my Java Web Application running **GlassFish server**. I have heard about ServletContextListener can be used to listen for a particular event, but i just want to get that detail coming from the GPS device and update my database.

Can anyone tell me how i can achieve this?

PS: It might be no-brainer but i'd really appreciate some help because i don't have much time.

Comment: What if you use your socket server to forward the GPS data to an existing database, and access it later via the webapp?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Glassfish, it is more general question about periodically retrieving data from somewhere....